# How to effectively detect negative cycles in graph?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, optimization

I proposed to check the edge weighs and then run shortest path and check if the shortest path weight is not going to $-\infty$. Any better ideas?

Comment: Exactly, e.g. run Floyd-Warshall and check if there exists a negative entry on the diagonal

Comment: This question has not yet been asnwered, how comes so?!

Bellman-Ford detects if there ar negative cycles - but without serious modification it does *not* return the negative cycles in a graph. I am not quite sure how such a modification would look like.

Answer (score 3):

The Bellman Ford algorithm detects negative cycles in O(mn).

It can also exhibit the (an) offending cycle.

Comment: without modifications, bellman-ford cannot output the (if so) existing negative cycles in a weightened graph.

Comment: question is how to detect, not how to exhibit

Comment: the answer could then be interpreted wrongly, as Bellman-Ford doesn't detect negative CycleS in a graph, but exits if any negative cycle has been found, which is a difference, because it does not detect _all_ negative cycles, but only one of them. 

The Problem of detecting all negative cycles in directed weighened graphs is more complex and rather unexplored. it requires a upper boundary on the cycles edge count, because else there are infinte possible cycles etc.